# No logro armar sentencia UPDATE con CTE en Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una funcionalidad que actualiza cada x segundos en la tabla `proxy_usuario` las columnas `consumo_actual` y `overcuote` para aquellos usuarios que pertenecen a grupos a los que se le controla la cuota de navegación. En el caso que consumo actual sobrepase a valor_cuota_individual, la columna `overcuote` se pone a 1 (`true`). Desde la aplicación es sencillo hacerlo pero intento pasarlo todo a una sentencia UPDATE para mejorar en rendimiento y la realidad es que no logro dar con la solución. La sentencia armada me devuelve cero registros actualizados siempre teneindo en cuenta por ejemplo que existen usuarios que en la tabla access_log_internet tienen por ejemplo 1300 MB en registros para una cuota asignada menor a 100 MB

El escenario es:

tabla `proxy_usuario (id, identificador, valor_cuota_individual, consumo_actual, grupo_id)`

tabla grupo_de_navegacion (id, nombre, chequear_consumo_de_cuota)`introducir el código aquí`

y tabla `access_log_internet (id, time_since_epoch, http_username)`

la tabla `access_log_internet` no está relacionada con la tabla `proxy_usuario` pero la columna http_username toma el mismo valor que la columna identificador de la tabla proxy_usuario. De esta tabla se puede calcular el consumo de cada usuario en la hora en curso, teniendo en cuenta que existe una tarea programada que elimina todos los registros cada 1 hora.

Intento armas la sentencia UPDATE de la siguiente manera, pero tengo errores en la sintaxis y quedé trabado en cómo concluir el SELECT CASE además.

```
WITH cte (id, identificador, cuota_asignada) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            t.id as id,
            t.identificador as identificador,
            t.valor_cuota_individual cuota_asignada
            FROM proxy_usuario t INNER JOIN grupo_de_navegacion g ON t.grupo_id = g.id where g.chequear_consumo_de_cuota = 1
    )
    UPDATE proxy_usuario T1
INNER JOIN cte ON T1.id = cte.id
SET
T1.consumo_actual =
    (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as consumo
        FROM access_log_internet internet
        WHERE internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683565204 AND 1683566372
        AND internet.http_reply_size > 0
        AND internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403')
        AND internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE')
        AND internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE')
        GROUP BY internet.http_username
        HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador
    ),
T1.overcuote = (
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN cte.cuota_asignada < (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as cuota_asignada
            FROM access_log_internet internet
            WHERE (internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683565204 AND 1683566372)
            AND (internet.http_reply_size > 0)
            AND (internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403'))
            AND (internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE'))
            AND (internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE'))
            GROUP BY internet.http_username
            HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador           
    ) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END
    FROM cte
)
```

**ACTUALIZACION**>
He encontrado la solución modificando ligeramente la sentenci anterior, cambiando la clasula `SELECT CASE` por `SELECT IF()`, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
WITH cte (id, identificador, cuota_asignada) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            t.id as id,
            t.identificador as identificador,
            t.valor_cuota_individual cuota_asignada
            FROM proxy_usuario t INNER JOIN grupo_de_navegacion g ON t.grupo_id = g.id where g.chequear_consumo_de_cuota = 1
    )
    UPDATE proxy_usuario T1
INNER JOIN cte ON T1.id = cte.id
SET
T1.consumo_actual =
    (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as consumo
        FROM access_log_internet internet
        WHERE internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683565204 AND 1683566372
        AND internet.http_reply_size > 0
        AND internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403')
        AND internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE')
        AND internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE')
        GROUP BY internet.http_username
        HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador
    ),
T1.overcuote = (
SELECT IF(cte.cuota_asignada < (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as consumo
            FROM access_log_internet internet
            WHERE (internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683565204 AND 1683566372)
            AND (internet.http_reply_size > 0)
            AND (internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403'))
            AND (internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE'))
            AND (internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE'))
            GROUP BY internet.http_username
            HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador
    ), 1, 0)
)
```